# xarray dataset selection method is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, dask, python-xarray

I have 37 years of NetCDF files with a daily time step and computing a function for each cell over all years (13513 days). The computation of this function is repeated for all cells. For this, I am using `xarray` and using `da.sel` approach but it is very slow and not making use of multiple cores of my laptop. I am struggling to figure out how to use dask in the current scenario. Any suggestions to improve/speed-up the code?

```
for c in range(len(df)):
    arr = np.array([])
    lon=df.X[c]
    lat=df.Y[c]
    for yr in range(1979,2016,1):
        ds = xr.open_dataset('D:/pr_'+str(yr)+'.nc')
        da = ds.var.sel(lon=lon, lat=lat, method='nearest')
        arr = np.concatenate([arr, da])

    fun = function(arr)
```

Comment: Avoid nested loops at all costs. At the moment, you're reading the same files multiple times (once for each line in `df`). Have the two methods follow one-another (reading data and analyzing  it). Also, it might be better to concatenate everything outside of the loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for [xarray.open_mfdataset](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html)

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('D:/pr_*.nc')
```

Your code is particularly slow because you repeatedly call `np.concatenate`.  Every time you call this function you have to copy all of the data that you've loaded so far.  This is quadratic in costs.

Comment: As @foxpal suggested, removing nested loops helped. Additionally, I read all data at once using `xarray.open_mfdataset` outside loop and used it for each cursor. The processing time reduced from 1.1sec to 0.02sec for each cursor with this approach